# Dart JS Interop - How to pass a callback object of functions

Tags: dart

I am using Pase.com with js SDK for the backend of my Dart App. This works fine apart from the parse sdk accepts an object of callback functions. In dart Im unsure how to do this, I can get single callbacks working fine. But Im completely lost here.

Normal Parse JS for registering a user

```js
var user = new Parse.User();
  user.set("username", "my name");
  user.set("password", "my pass");
  user.set("email", "email@example.com");

  // other fields can be set just like with Parse.Object
  user.set("phone", "415-392-0202");

  user.signUp(null, {
    success: function(user) {
      // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
      // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });
```

My Dart code

```dart
void registerSuccess(user) {
    print("success");
  }

  void registerFailed(user, error){
    print("fail");
  }

  void register(String email, String password)
  {
    js.scoped(() {

      var parse = js.context.Parse;


      var parseUser = new js.Proxy(parse.User);

      parseUser.set("username", "my name");
      parseUser.set("password", "my pass");
      parseUser.set("email", "email@example.com");

      print(parseUser.getEmail());

      var callbackSuccess = new js.Callback.once(() => registerSuccess());
      var callbackFailed = new js.Callback.once(() => registerFailed());

      parseUser.signUp(null,{"success":callbackSuccess, "error": callbackFailed});

      //parseUser.signUp();
    });
  }
```

Also the callback function needs accept vars passed back from the js.

Any help would be a appreciated, I have be spinning my wheels for 2 days on this.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of :

```dart
var callbackSuccess = new js.Callback.once(() => registerSuccess());
var callbackFailed = new js.Callback.once(() => registerFailed());
parseUser.signUp(null,{"success":callbackSuccess, "error": callbackFailed});
```

use :

```dart
var callbackSuccess = new js.Callback.once(registerSuccess);
var callbackFailed = new js.Callback.once(registerFailed);
parseUser.signUp(null, js.map({"success":callbackSuccess, "error": callbackFailed}));
```

Comment: Now Im getting 

Uncaught Class '() => void' has no instance method 'call'.

NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'call'
Receiver: Closure: (dynamic) => void from Function 'registerFailed':.
Arguments: [Instance of 'Proxy', Instance of 'Proxy', Instance of 'Proxy']

Comment: You get this error because `registerFailed` accept only 2 parameters but seams to be called with 3 parameters. You have to change `registerFailed` to `void registerFailed(user, error, WAT)`.

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin, what library is being used here? I'm not able to find js.scoped and other methods used in this question. `dart:js` does not have them.